# Refreshing Grid Data (Vaadin 8)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have a data provider that fetches data from database and I'm keeping my data as a list.

```
List<Person> myList= new ArrayList<>(dao.getAllPersons());
ListDataProvider<Person> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(myList);
//...
grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
```

When I delete some data from my database it doesn't refresh immediately. I have to refresh my page to see the difference.

```
dao.deletePerson(...);
dataProvider.refreshAll();
```

refreshAll() doesn't work at all. How can I refresh it?

Comment: If memory consumption is an issue some day, you should switch to an own data provider (e.g. with fetch and count callback) that directly queries from the database but paged.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich Developing mini-project to learn Vaadin but I will consider it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

```
dataProvider.getItems().remove(item); // Removed item from list
dao.deletePerson(...); // and removed it from my database too
```

After that:

```
 dataProvider.refreshAll();
```

**EDIT:**

It's not the best solution.

> If memory consumption is an issue some day, you should switch to an own data provider (e.g. with fetch and count callback) that directly queries from the database but paged.
>
> – [@Steffen Harbich's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812137/refreshing-grid-data-vaadin-8#comment78589700_45812137)